# How to replace the data array of my ChartJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, chart.js

I am doing a project where I need to be able to change the data array of a chart with a totally different one. My code is working for the labels of the chart, but the data is not changing, and I dont understand why. Hope you can help me, thanks in advance.

Here is my code :

```
var label = [];
var testArray= [{"production":"12","mois":"janvier"},{"production":"5","mois":"février"},{"production":"9","mois":"mars"},{"production":"17","mois":"avril"},{"production":"6","mois":"mai"},{"production":"8","mois":"juin"},{"production":"17","mois":"juillet"},{"production":"7","mois":"aout"},{"production":"10","mois":"septembre"}];
var chartData = {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
        label: '# of Votes',
        data: [7, 4, 3, 5, 2, 3]
    }]
};
var newdata = [];

function updateData(){
    chartData.datasets.data = testArray.map(function (item) {
        return item.production;
    });

    chartData.labels = testArray.map(function (item) {
        return item.mois;
    });
    graphique.destroy();
    graphInit();

}


function graphInit() {
    graphique = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'bar',
        data: chartData,
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside function `updateData`, you need to access the `data` with `chartData.datasets[0].data`. Further you should update `data` with an array of  `number` instead of `string`. Use [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert `string` to `number` as follows:

```
chartData.datasets[0].data = testArray.map(function (item) {
    return Number(item.production);
});
```

this can also be written in a simpler way:

```
chartData.datasets[0].data = testArray.map(item => Number(item.production));
```

Also instead of `graphique.destroy()` and `graphInit()` you can simply use `graphique.update()`. Maybe this answer is of some further help too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091960/2358409.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried both of your codes, and it is still having the same issue (labels updating correctly, new data not showing on chartJS) When I do a console.log(chartData.datasets.data) I have the correct data in it. So I guess the problem is between the array and chartjs

Comment: Also instead of `graphique.destroy()` and `graphInit()` you should simply use `graphique.update()`

Comment: Yeah you're right. Still, I have the issue. I tried to put the data (numbers) into the label and it works. I think the issue is the "chartData.datasets.data" not linking with the chart or whatever :/

Comment: I missed that one...you should use `chartData.datasets[0].data` because you want to access the first and unique dataset.

Comment: Damn, thanks a lot it is working. I knew there was something like that, when I tested this solution, I used chartData.datasets[0].data[0], which was obviously not working, but I never tried chartData.datasets[0] Thanks a lot for your help and your time :)