# Chart.js Glitches when filtering table

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I have a table displayed on my WordPress page, and I have implemented a chartjs chart, I want the chart to update whenever the table is filtered, so I added a SetInterval to the script (which I know isn't the best option). When the table is filtered, only the axis of the chart changes, the graph remains the same until I hover on the graph and it becomes to glitch between the current graph and the supposed filtered graph. Below is my code:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("QGL_Chart").getContext('2d');
ctx.canvas.width = 934;
ctx.canvas.height = 400;

var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: data = {
        labels: ['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24'],
        datasets: [


            {
                type: 'line',
                label: "Price",
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-b',
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: '#ad3865',
                borderColor: '#ad3865',
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'round',
                pointBorderColor: '#ad3865',
                pointBackgroundColor: '#ad3865',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 4,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(238, 79, 75)',
                pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(238, 79, 75)',
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 3,
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [price1, price2, price3, price4, price5, price6, price7, price8, price9, price10, price11, price12, price13, price14, price15, price16, price17, price18, price19, price20, price21, price22, price23, price24],
            },
            {

                label: "Volume",
                fill: false,
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-a',
                lineTension: 0.1,
                backgroundColor: '#d9d9d9',
                borderColor: '#d9d9d9',
                borderCapStyle: 'butt',
                borderDash: [],
                borderWidth: 0.5, borderDashOffset: 0.0,
                borderJoinStyle: 'miter',
                pointBorderColor: '#d9d9d9',
                pointBackgroundColor: '#d9d9d9',
                pointBorderWidth: 1,
                pointHoverRadius: 4,
                pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(210, 221, 72)',
                pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(210, 221, 72)',
                pointHoverBorderWidth: 3,
                pointRadius: 5,
                pointHitRadius: 10,
                data: [vol1, vol2, vol3, vol4, vol5, vol6, vol7, vol8, vol9, vol10, vol11, vol12, vol13, vol14, vol15, vol16, vol17, vol18, vol19, vol20, vol21, vol22, vol23, vol24],

            },


        ]
    },
    options: {
        tooltips: {
            mode: 'index'
        },
        title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Share Price - Past 7 Days',
            fontSize: '20',
            fontFamily: 'Open Sans, sans-serif',
            // fontColor
            // fontStyle
            // padding
            // lineHeight
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                barPercentage: 0.6,
                ticks: {
                    min: 0
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{

                ticks: {
                    reverse: false,
                    // stepSize: 6,
                    min: 0
                },
                position: "left",
                id: "y-axis-a",
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'EUR/MWh'
                }
            }, {
                scaleLabel: {
                    display: true,
                    labelString: 'MWh'
                },
                position: "right",
                id: "y-axis-b",
                ticks: {
                    min: 0
                }

            }]
        },
        animation: {
            duration: 0
        }
    }
});

}, 5000);
```

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html

Comment: Invoke `chart.update()` after the data on the existing chart configuration was changed (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60091960/2358409).

Comment: @uminder thanks a lot for your comment! it helped me solve my problem and it also helped make my code better!